# Why is location structure a requirement?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Recently I went to update my address to "Northern NJ". I did this because it is my understanding that saying your *actual* address can cause people to dismiss your CV out of hand (for example they may view your commute as too long). However, now the site is claiming that I haven't filled out my address.

This strikes me as failing in one of the seven classic blunders. [Or at least it fails in one of the items from this list.](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/)

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree!  It's quite annoying that a location with a specificity of a city is so often required.

Comment: Well, at least they haven't gotten involved in a land war in Asia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We require a minimum granularity of a city because we allow search by location in [candidate search](http://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/careers/uk/platform/candidate-search) and this allows employers to search for CVs in a specific city. It also surfaces your CV if they search by country or state / region.

This also works for the 'Where I'd like to work' section of your CV; this surfaces your CV to employers searching in a matching location. Note your CV will be visible in these locations **only** if you have already specified a *Current Location*; that's one of the requirements to get into the CV database.

[image: Edit Job Status]
[image: Where I'd like to work]

However, I get your point that you don't necessarily want to surface that information on your CV when it's being viewed so as not to introduce possible bias based upon your location. We're discussing internally some UI for this and I'll update when we have further information.

**UPDATE**

That particular field isn't required on the CV. You can leave it blank and use the **Where you'd like to work** section instead; that section allows up to country granularity. This means you don't see any location on your CV but you won't be surfaced in employer searches because *Current Location* is required information to get into the CV database. You can still use your CV to apply to jobs.

Comment: Where does one get to that screen? Not seeing it on CV edit screen or CV settings screen

Comment: @cwallenpoole I've updated the answer to show how you get to that screen!